# Writing full path of an application in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to run a command on a remote machine like this

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteMachine -Credential $Cred `
    -ScriptBlock { echo MYPASS | "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" --set-password}
```

However, I get this error

```
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\anydesk.ps1:14 char:33
+ ... o MYPASS | "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" --set-pass ...
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
```

It seems that there is a problem with specifying the path of the program when using pipes. How can I fix that?

UPDATE:

Since I want to use that in a scriptblock with multiple commands and also passing variables to the scriptblock, the following modification doesn't work either.

```
$NewPassword = 'Mahmood00'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteMachine -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {        
         & {
         Param(param1)
 'echo $param1 | "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" --set-password'
          } } ArgumentList = $Using:NewPassword
```

That has syntax problem. If I use

```
$NewPassword = 'Mahmood00'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteMachine -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {        
         & Param(param1){
 'echo $param1 | "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" --set-password'
          } } ArgumentList = $Using:NewPassword
```

I get this error:

```
A Using variable cannot be retrieved. A Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command,
```

UPDATE 2:

Using a local variable also doesn't work. See below:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteMachine -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {        
         &   {
         $param1 = $Using:NewPassword
         cmd /c 'echo $param1 | "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" --set-password'
          } }
```

The password is actually $param1 and not the value of that variable.

Comment: I would suggest executing a remote "cmd /c" for the entire pipe.

Comment: @harrymc: Excuse me, It seems that I am not able to use variable with that idea. When I use `cmd /c 'echo $Using:NewPassword | "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe"' --set-password` the String $Using:NewPassword is set for the password and not the value of that variable.

Comment: @mahmood ... I suppose this way does not work, correct? `$NewPassword = 'Mahmood00';
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteMachine -ScriptBlock {$Using:NewPassword | "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" '--set-password';} -Credential $Cred;` I don't have anydesk to test so just curious. If I could confirm, I would write up an answer for you.

Comment: Can **AnyDesk** be launched from a **PowerShell** console? If so, ditch the shelling out to **cmd.exe** through **PowerShell**. Then your `Invoke-Command` would be more straight-forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$NewPassword = 'Mahmood00'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteMachine -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
    Param($NewPassword)
    $Expression = 'echo {0} | "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" --set-password' -f $NewPassword
    Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/c $Expression"
} -ArgumentList $NewPassword
```

You don't need `$Using:Varname` for this, you can just pass it to the Scriptblock normally

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest executing a remote "cmd /c" for the entire pipe.
For passing environment variables from your computer to the remote, use the
`ArgumentList` parameter.

Without testing, something like:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteMachine -Credential $Cred
-ScriptBlock {
  Param ($param1)
  'echo $param1 | "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" --set-password'}
  ArgumentList = $Using:NewPassword
```

See the documentation of
[Invoke-Command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: Please see the updated post.

Comment: See [Bug report #5722 : $Using variable is not available when run Invoke-Command to different versions of PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5722) for several workarounds. Or store the value in a local variable.

Comment: I didn't fully understand the workaround. However, the local variable methods doesn't work either. See the updated post.

Comment: Another option is to pass the password to a batch file where the batch file is running on the remote machine. Then there is no need to call the command in the scriptblock.